# Scala: How to read the line from terminal and store it as a string?

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a framework for executing external commands with Scala. I have a scenario in which, I am downloading a zip file using the `wget` command and decompressing that file using the `unzip` command.

To execute these commands, I have done some implementation as follows,

```
case class wget_builder[wget <: CommandExecutor](i: Seq[String]) {
    import Cmd_Framework.wget_builder._
    protected def this() = this(Seq.empty[String])
    def URL(url: String): wget_builder[wget with URL] = new wget_builder(i :+ url)
    def optionBackground(): wget_builder[wget with WGETOptions] = new wget_builder(i :+ "-b")
    def optionNoVerbose(): wget_builder[wget with WGETOptions] = new wget_builder(i :+ "-nv")
    def build(implicit ev: wget =:= full_wget_command) = ("wget " + i.mkString(" ")).!!
}

object wget_builder {
    def apply(): wget_builder[wget_builder.EmptyCommand] = new wget_builder
    sealed trait EmptyCommand extends CommandExecutor
    sealed trait URL extends CommandExecutor
    sealed trait Output extends CommandExecutor
    sealed trait WGETOptions extends CommandExecutor
    type full_wget_command = EmptyCommand with URL with WGETOptions
}

case class unzip_builder[unzip <: CommandExecutor](i: Seq[String]) {
    import Cmd_Framework.unzip_builder._
    protected def this() = this(Seq.empty[String])
    def optionJ(): unzip_builder[unzip with UZOptions] = new unzip_builder(i :+ "-j")
    def optionQ(): unzip_builder[unzip with UZOptions] = new unzip_builder(i :+ "-q")
    def zipFileName(file: String): unzip_builder[unzip with File] = new unzip_builder(i :+ file)
    def build(implicit ev: unzip =:= full_unzip_command) = println(("unzip " + i.mkString(" ")).!!)
}

object unzip_builder {
    def apply(): unzip_builder[unzip_builder.EmptyCommand] = new unzip_builder
    sealed trait EmptyCommand extends CommandExecutor
    sealed trait UZOptions extends CommandExecutor
    sealed trait File extends CommandExecutor
    type full_unzip_command = EmptyCommand with UZOptions with File
}
```

I invoke the `wget_builder` as something like this,

```
wget_builder().URL("http://archives.textfiles.com/100.zip").optionNoVerbose().build
```

It works fine and the zip file gets downloaded and a statement appears after the successful execution as

```
2019-11-25 19:38:26 URL:http://archives.textfiles.com/100.zip [1135379/1135379] -> "100.zip" [1]
```

I know, this is the same statement a terminal will return when I run the command

```
wget "http://archives.textfiles.com/100.zip" -nv
```

What I'm trying to do is, I need to extract the above mentioned statement and take the file name, in this case `100.zip` and pass this name to the `unzip_builder`.

Is there anyway I can achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why from the terminal? The `ProcessBuilder` method `!!` returns the process's StdOut as the result. Why can't it be scraped from that? (BTW, I'd advise against `mkString()`. Use `("wget" +: i).!!` instead.)

Comment: When I execute the builder, it doesn't return any StdOut, the object is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `wget` writes its results to StdErr, you'll have to use a `ProcessLogger` to capture the output for further processing.

```
import sys.process._

val errBuf = new StringBuilder

Seq("wget", "http://archives.textfiles.com/100.zip", "-nv")
   .!!(ProcessLogger(_ => (), errBuf.addAll))

val filename = errBuf.toString.replaceAll(".*-> \"(.*)\".*", "$1")
//filename: String = 100.zip
```